# Help verify my understanding of groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I just learned the definition of groups today an would like help in verifying my understanding. Please point out any mistakes or misconceptions in my examples.

**Definition:** A group is a pair $G = (G,*)$ consisting of a set of elements $G$, and a binary operation $*$ on G such that:

• $G$ has an identity element

• The operation is associative

• Each element $g \in G$ has an inverse

**An example:**

The pair $(\Bbb Z, +)$ is a group.

**Explanation:**

$\Bbb Z$ $= \{...-2, -1, 0, 1, 2 ...\}$ is the set $(G)$ and $+$ is the associative operation. The element $0 \in \Bbb Z$ is an identity because $$a+0=0+a=a$$ for any element $a \in \Bbb Z$. Every element $a \in \Bbb Z$ also has an additive inverse such that $$a + (-a)=(-a) + a = 0$$

**Non-example:**

$(\Bbb N, -)$ is not a group.

**Explanation:**

$\Bbb N$ $ = \{0, 1, 2,...\}$ is the set $(G)$ and $-$ is the associative operation.

There is no identity element for this set because $$a-0=0$$ but $$0-a\neq a$$

There is also no inverse element because $$a - (-a) \neq 0$$

**EDIT**

A major mistake was made...

$(\Bbb N, -)$ is not a group because subtraction is not associative and it isn't a binary operation of the natural numbers.

Comment: Subtraction is not an associative operation.  Note that $(9 - 2) - 3 \neq 9 - (2 - 3)$.  Also, subtraction is not a binary operation on the natural numbers since $1 - 2 \notin \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: I see, that's a little embarrassing...that's what I get for doing math at 2:40 in the morning.

Comment: In group theory, you should see $a-b$ as $a+c$ where $c=-b$.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.